# Markov chain: Sunny or raining?

Tags: markov-chains

Suppose that the probability that it rain today is $p=0.3$ if neither of the last two days was rainy, but $0.6$ if at least one of the last two days was rainy. Let the wether at the $n^{th}$ day, $W_n$, be $R$ for rain and $S$ for sunny. $W_n$ is not a markov chain but the weather for the last two day $X_n=(W_n,W_{n-1})$ is a Markov chain with four states $\{RR,RS,SR,SS\}$. Compute it's transition probability.

I have that $$p\{X_{n+1}=RR\mid X_n=RR\}=p\{W_{n+1}=R\mid W_n=R,W_{n-1}=R\}=0.6.$$

I would say that
$$p\{X_{n+1}=RR\mid X_n=RS\}=p\{W_{n+1}=R,W_n=R\mid W_n=R,W_{n-1}=S\}=p\{W_{n+1}=R\mid W_n=R,W_{n-1}=S\}=0.6$$

and

$$p\{X_{n+1}=RR\mid X_n=SR\}=p\{W_{n+1}=R,W_n=R\mid W_n=S,W_{n-1}=R\}=0$$

because it's impossible that $W_n=R$ and $W_n=S$, but in the correction of my exercise, they say exactly the opposite, i.e. $p\{X_{n+1}=RR\mid X_n=RS\}=0$ and $p\{X_{n+1}=RR\mid X_n=SR\}=0.6$. Then who is right ?
(thanks to give me some explanation if they are right because I don't understand why).

Comment: Your answer looks right to me. The likely reason for the difference is that they order the R/S pairs the opposite way to you. i.e. RS for you means "sunny then rainy" but for them means "rainy then sunny".

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING:**  *This is post may seem long, but I just presented the answer in a way that I thought would be most easy to read. Hope it helps clear up some confusion.*

I'm not sure how you're classifying your states so for clarity
by X<sub>n</sub> = RS I mean W<sub>n-1</sub> = R and W<sub>n</sub> = S.

Now to map the behavior of the weather based on given information we can say:

P(W<sub>n</sub> = R) = 0.3 if X<sub>n-1</sub> = SS

P(W<sub>n</sub> = R) = 0.6 if X<sub>n-1</sub> = (SR or RS or RR)

Therefore we can conclude:

P(X<sub>n</sub> = SS|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SS) = P(W<sub>n</sub> = S|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SS) = 0.7

P(X<sub>n</sub> = SR|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SS) = P(W<sub>n</sub> = R|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SS) = 0.3

P(X<sub>n</sub> = RS|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SS) = 0

P(X<sub>n</sub> = RR|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SS) = 0

P(X<sub>n</sub> = SS|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SR) = 0

P(X<sub>n</sub> = SR|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SR) = 0

P(X<sub>n</sub> = RS|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SR) = P(W<sub>n</sub> = S|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SR) = 0.4

P(X<sub>n</sub> = RR|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SR) = P(W<sub>n</sub> = S|X<sub>n-1</sub> = SS) = 0.6

P(X<sub>n</sub> = SS|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RS) = P(W<sub>n</sub> = S|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RS) = 0.4

P(X<sub>n</sub> = SR|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RS) = P(W<sub>n</sub> = R|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RS) = 0.6

P(X<sub>n</sub> = RS|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RS) = 0

P(X<sub>n</sub> = RR|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RS) = 0

P(X<sub>n</sub> = SS|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RR) = 0

P(X<sub>n</sub> = SR|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RR) = 0

P(X<sub>n</sub> = RS|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RR) = P(W<sub>n</sub> = S|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RR) = 0.4

P(X<sub>n</sub> = RR|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RR) = P(W<sub>n</sub> = R|X<sub>n-1</sub> = RR) = 0.6

From this information it is easy to build a transition probability matrix.